# Wrapping xml output in XStream with another element

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xstream

I have this class:

```
Class B {
  private String D;
  private String E;
}
```

Using XStream, I would like to generate XML like this, where elements A and B are generated in the XML, even though they don't exist in the java.:

```
<A>
        <B>
                <C>
                        <D/>
                        <E/>
                </C>
        </B>
</A>
```

Possible?

Comment: Shouldn't `class B` be `class C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Since you are looking for an annotation based solution, you may be interested in the `@XmlPath` extension in MOXy.

**B**

The `@XmlPath` annotation allows you to specify your mapping as an XPath.

```
package forum11334385;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="A")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class B {

    @XmlPath("B/C/D/text()")
    private String D;

    @XmlPath("B/C/E/text()")
    private String E;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum11334385;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(B.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum11334385/input.xml");
        B b = (B) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(b, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
   <B>
      <C>
         <D>Foo</D>
         <E>Bar</E>
      </C>
   </B>
</A>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: I've read your article http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html, so I find myself leaning to JAXB now. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement and register a custom converter in the XStream instance.
For example:

```
XStream xstream = new new XStream(...);
xstream.registerConverter(new BConverter());
xstream.toXML(new B(),new BufferedWriter(...));
```

Example of the converter implementation:

```
class BConverter implements com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter{

@Override
public void marshal(Object o, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext mc) {
    B target=(B)o;
    writer.startNode("A");
    writer.startNode("B");
    writer.startNode("C");
    writer.startNode("D");
    writer.setValue(target.getD());
    writer.endNode();//end node D
    writer.startNode("E");
    writer.setValue(target.getE());
    writer.endNode();//end node E
    writer.endNode();//end node C
    writer.endNode();//end node B
    writer.endNode();//end node A
}

@Override
public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext uc) {
    //unmarshalizing logic here
}

@Override
public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
    return type.equals(B.class);
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Let me look into this.

Comment: I've marked it as accepted, although I was hoping there was some way of doing this via the annotations provided in XStream.  I didn't really want to write a whole bunch of code.  But if this is what I got to do, so be it.